# New command to insert a couple of red XXX as placeholder?

Tags: color, macros

I seem to misunderstand the documentation, as

```
\newcommand\ph{\textcolor{red}{XXX}}
```

causes pdflatex to halt. I'm not sure if this is the error:

```
! Argument of \sf@@subfloat has an extra }.
```

And I also don't know what it is referring to.

What I want to achieve is that

```
\myshortcommand
```

turns into

```
\textcolor{red}{XXX}
```

so the output is

XXX (in red)

Comment: Your suggested command works just fine, as my answer indicates. You will need to provide more detail, preferably with a *minimal working example*.

Comment: in your caption needs one command a `\protect`

Comment: This `\newcommand` definition doesn't cause the problem. `\sf@@subfloat` is defined by the `subfig` package. So I guess, the problem is caused by a fragile command within a subfigure caption. You might look for that.

Comment: @None: You may also want to go ahead and delete this question (I read from your comment to the answer that it was just a problem with a typo, so the question is no longer relevant). For being able to delete, you have to register I guess.

Comment: @Hendrik: The question is no longer relevant with regard to the problem caused by my typo, but it's a valid question with a valid answer, so it may solve somebody's problem. I should have commented the cause here instead of in Harald's answer though.

Comment: @None: I can't really see that this question is helpful since it doesn't tell me the code that produced the error. So I also fail to see how it could solve somebody's problem. In the future, please do provide a [minimal example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/1235) that illustrates your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{color}
\newcommand\ph{\textcolor{red}{XXX}}
\begin{document}
Foo \ph\space bar.
\end{document}
```

works just fine.

Comment: Oops. I only now saw that the label argument of subfloat has an extra } (though hidden by my editor's syntax higlighting. :-( Thanks nonetheless for testing.